# Laravel Divided Query Overwrites Previous Variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What I am trying to achieve is to create a query and use it with multiple endings:

For example

```
$query = User::where('is_admin', true);

if ($query->where('badge', 'red')->exists())
{
  //do something
}

if ($query->where('badge', 'green')->exists())
{
  //do something
}

$query->get();

$query->first();
```

With this, the `$query` variable gets overwritten every time the query is finished therefore it is not possible to re-use `$query`;

The current solution I have is utilizing `clone`

```
$query = User::where('is_admin', true);

$query1 = clone $query;
if ($query1->where('badge', 'red')->exists())
{
  //do something
}

$query2 = clone $query
if ($query2->where('badge', 'green')->exists())
{
  //do something
}

$query3 = clone $query;
$query3->get();

$query4 = clone $query;
$query4->first();
```

> The example is used just to get the point across, not a real
> life scenario.

I guess it works and does what I want, just does not feel like a **laravel** way of doing something, quite verbose and it gets worse with more complicated logic.

The goal is to re-use the same variable without overwriting it every time I finalize the query.

Does anybody have a better solution to this?

Is there a way to somehow break the reactivity of the `$query` variable?

Thanks

Comment: $query = User::where('is_admin', true)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant option is to make use of [Laravel Local Query Scopes.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include administrators.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeAdmins($query)
    {
        return $query->where('is_admin', true);
    }

  
}
```

Now, to utilize the newly created local scope:

```php
if (User::admins()->where('badge', 'red')->exists())
{
  //do something
}

if (User::admins()->where('badge', 'green')->exists())
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a more elegant way, but I am afraid in the long run it would make my models "obese" eventually. 

But you are definitely right the laravel way would be to utilise smart scopes for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For starters, $query doesn't sound like a good name for fetching Users that are admins.

so, **let's quickly change it so it's more clear for us to read and think**

```
$user_admins = User::where('is_admin', true);

if ($user_admins->where('badge', 'red')->exists())
{
  //do something
} 

if ($user_admins->where('badge', 'green')->exists())
{
  //do something
}
```

okay, so we grabbed admins, let's iterate through them with a **foreach loop**

```
$user_admins = User::where('is_admin', true);

foreach($user_admins as $admin) {
    if ($admin->badge == 'green') {
         // do something
    } else if ($admin->badge == 'red') {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

now, whenever you change the $admin variable inside the loop, it will change **that individual** admin.

also query is the "question" eloquent is "asking" the database (for example: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_admin=true"; so **query does not not refer to the result**.

**note** you could also use a switch statement if you have a lot of logic, it would look like this:

```
$user_admins = User::where('is_admin', true);

foreach($user_admins as $admin) {
    switch($admin->badge) {
        case 'green:
            // do something
            break;
        case 'red:
            // do something else
            break;
        case 'ltblue:
        case 'blue:
            // do same things for ltblue and blue
            break;
        default: break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question to be more clear. Also your answer is missing the `->get();` at the end of the variable so that you can use it with a foreach. Regardless, not the answer to the question